# Google Sheets Filter Comma Separated List Value

Tags: regex, csv, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula

I have the following scenario.

- Column A: A unique list of product IDs
- Column B: A joined list of orders against each product
- Column C: A joined list of orders that have already been printed.
- Column D: ***My desired output*** - a joined list of orders that have yet to be printed

[image]

I am trying to calculate column D using a combination of `FILTER` and `REGEXMATCH`, but haven't gotten anywhere with it.

I have tried using this [post](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/comma-separated-values-as-criteria-in-filter-function-sheets/) as a guide. But I am getting hung up on filtering a separated list that is stored in a single cell.

Comment: Here is a blank sheet that has been specifically created for your question.  If you paste some data in there, it will be easier for others to help.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pLo9y7gpgLmvXKeV1dt94GyaDNwQ2QQQekgcw6ws8FQ/edit

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a solution. Formula for Column D is as follows:

`=JOIN(", ",FILTER(SPLIT(B3,", ",TRUE,TRUE),NOT(COUNTIF(SPLIT(C3,", ",TRUE,TRUE),SPLIT(B3,", ",TRUE,TRUE)))))`

There very well might be a more elegant solution, but this is what I got to work for now.